# How to get particular date in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `mystores`
WHERE `status`='0'
  AND DATE(`create_date`) < '2014-10-23'
  AND DATE(`create_date`) > '2014-10-17'
```

and it shows all the records between 2014-10-18 and 2014-10-22.
Now I want only 2014-10-18, 2014-10-20 and 2014-10-22 date's records.
If I run this query tomorrow, it should show 2014-10-19, 2014-10-21 and 2014-10-23

and My PHP code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `mystores` WHERE `status`='0' AND  DATE(`create_date`) < '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"))."' AND DATE(`create_date`) > '".date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days"))."'";
```

Is there any possible to get these records?
Thanks

Comment: What's the question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `mystores`
WHERE `status`='0'
  AND DATE(`create_date`) in (curdate() - interval 2 day,
                              curdate() - interval 4 day,
                              curdate() - interval 6 day)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This what I want